# UIScrollView - Showing user more content is available on scroll

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, scroll, scrollbar

I have a similar problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888647/uiscrollview-showing-the-scroll-bar)

I have a scrollview where more data is visible to the user if the user scrolls to the left or scrolls to the bottom. But I am unable to find a way to tell the user that more content is available on scroll. It is not intuitive and only by experimenting, the user will find out about the scroll option.

Is there any way I can show/tell the user that scrolling is available.

Using `[scrollView flashScrollIndicators]` is not exactly useful as it just flashes the indicators and it is so quick that the user would surely fail to see it.

It would be great if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the way I did it...

I put an image on my scroll view ( for example an arrow pointing left). So using the function mentioned below, whenever the user loads the view, the image would show (telling that more content is there in the right). When the user comes to the right most of the scrollview, the image would disappear and when he scrolls again to the left, it would reappear...

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView1 {
    if (scrollView1.contentOffset.x == scrollView1.contentSize.width - scrollView1.frame.size.width) 
    {
        // reached the bottom
        NSLog(@"reached right");
        self.imageView.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        self.imageView.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i not sure but may be u can set a timer to flash indicators so that it stays there.......