# Images not showing up when architecture set to 64 bit

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimageview, 64-bit, arm64

For transitioning my app to 64-bit, I changed the Architectures build setting to:

> ARCHS = "$(ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT)";

App is runnig fine except that some of the images are not showing up (blank). Why would it happen? any clues?

Comment: So only when running in 64 bit do the images fail to appear? Or now some images never appear? Simulator or device or both? We need more info update the question please.

Comment: yes only running on a 64 bit device (simulator or iphone 5s) some images never appear on any run, and works perfect on 32 bit device (simulator or device).

Comment: ive observed that most of those failed images include whose view was built using xib layout and image assigned through code, others include those that were custom images on uibarbuttonitems

Comment: Post a demo project with one such image on Dropbox. My guess at this point is that the image decoding code in ios may be the issue, along with a possibly improperly coded image. For jpgs, ios uses the integral array processor and that code is quite complex.

Comment: fixed that, see answer

Comment: hi @Firdous i have same problems this solution not work for me all the working fine in iphone  5 but in iphone 6 device and simulator not display button images and `imageview `images. please give me any solution . Thanks in advanced.

Comment: @Ilesh r u sure you dont have any imageview category in directory

Comment: yaa @Firdous please give me a any solution ...

Comment: @DavidH any comments..

Comment: @Ilesh one of you needs to post a demo project with at least one image that does not load. Throw in a bounty for good measure!

Comment: i was unable to repro the issue in a demo project, since it was only caused by this category, @Ilesh might want to share

Comment: Hi guys , My problems solve through replace `float` to change `CGFloat` in project . Thank you guys for rpl

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answer lies here:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/922989#922989

I found the reason. In a viewController, which was not yet allocated, but included in the app, there was following implemented (in the .m-file above implementation viewController):

```
@implementation UIImageView (UIScrollView)
- (void)setAlpha:(float)alpha {
..........(no difference if here is some code or not) ...............
  [super setAlpha:alpha];
}
@end
```

Putting above in comment solved the problem, even though the button which didn't display the image wasn't in a scrollview.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This saved me a lot of time tracking down the issue. Apparently, we also had a similar category.

Comment: I'm guessing the category came from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8607393/123269

Comment: Note that 'alpha' is a CGFloat, which is a float on 32 bit systems and a double on 64 bit systems. The above category declares it as a float in all cases.

Answer (score 4):

Update the Data structure used in code according to 64 bits for example replace  `Float` with `CGFloat`,(if not working Than also change `int` type with `NSInteger`)
[see here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925620/images-disappearing-after-setting-valid-architecture-to-arm64)

 In my case replace  `Float` with `CGFloat` and solve my problem (simplest way to replace `float` to `CGFloat` )

```
#define float CGFloat
```

Write in .pch file and check it working or not.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It fixed my issue to change

```
- (void)setAlpha:(float)alpha {
```

to:

```
- (void) setAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha {
```