# Images from Bundle doesn't show using iPad Retina 64-bit and real device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I created a photos scroll app using UIPageviewcontroller (scroll type) which using viewcontroller to get images. The app works fine in iPad and iPad retina simulator. But it didn't show any images in iPad retina 64-bit and real devices.

My code is:

```
UIImageView *background =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenHeightPortrait,screenWidthPortrait)];
NSString *imageFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.mainImageLink ofType:nil];
background.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageFile];
[self.view addSubview:background];
```

self.mainImageLink is an NSArray element. For example is "image1.png".

I tried to find solutions in SO and tried:

- Make sure that "image1.png" is case-sensitive correct and inside the copy bundle resources.
- Remove "image1.png" from copy bundle resource, clear cache and then add it again.
- Put "image1.png" into a real folder called "images" (it shows in Xcode in blue folder icon), make sure that it's in the copy bundle resource and then change self.mainImageLink into: "images/image1.png"
- Tried the above trial, using self.mainImageLink: "image1.png" and NSString *imageFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.mainImageLink ofType:nil inDirectory:@"images"];
- Clear build cache (cmd+shift+option+k)
- remove derived data using rm -r /Users/User/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData/
- If I'm NSLog(@"image:%@",imageFile); the result is:`image: /Users/my_user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/E16A2B0F-F766-41E4-A973-67CA79ED0F9C/myApp.app/images/image1.png` and I make sure that it's in copy bundle resource and found the image using Finder

Is there anything that I missed? Really appreciate any clues or hints..

Thanks SO!

PS:
I'm using XCode 5.1.1 and SDK iOS 7 + OSX 10.8.5 + MBP 2.5Ghz Core2Duo

Comment: Did you try to set height and width to a specific float number? If it happens only in 64bit devices, it might be a problem of casting `float` and `CGFloat`.

Comment: do you mean about UIImageView's frame? I'm using: CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
    CGFloat screenWidthPortrait = screenSize.width;
    CGFloat screenHeightPortrait = screenSize.height;

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. Just try to use a static number.Just in case.

Comment: sorry, didn't work. I tried: UIImageView *background =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768)];

Comment: I tried to copy the image to documents directory. But it still only showing at iPad & iPad retina simulator. Not showing at iPad retina 64-bit and my iPad 2 device. Any other clues?

Comment: I gave up. I'm using images.xcassets and UIImage imageNamed:myImageName

Comment: After I was suffering with memory problems due to using "imageNamed"..I'm trying again to use my prior method. This time, I was copying the files to project folder using Finder then add them using XCode instead of directly add the files from XCode. And it works...I'm wondering whether directly add from XCode (and checked "copy item's into destination group's folder") is not working?

Comment: You may check this [SO Answer][1]. It may solve your problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20944188/1540450

Answer (score 0):

Some other user have also same problem for 64 bit devices. Some images are not displaying from bundle in 64-bit device though implemented correctly.

You may check this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20944188/1540450). It may solve your problem.