# Images Disappearing after setting "Valid Architecture" to "arm64"

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, ios8.1

I am updating an existing app from another developer to support 64 bit devices as Apple is going to make it compulsory.

I added :-
Architectures : $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
valid Arch    : armv7 arm64

Problem :-
The slot items after stopping the rotation disappear. this happens only on i5,i6 n i6+ devices only. (Working perfect on i4s n iPad(s))

Failed Attempts:
1) Converted all float values to CGFloat for if the float might be loosing values.
2) tried to use xib of i4 in place of i5s

P.S: 
This question might be a duplicate of "[Images not showing up when architecture set to 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855176/images-not-showing-up-when-architecture-set-to-64-bit)"

But, the above solution is so much code specific to the guy's personal problem.
So I am asking for a more generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

Update the Data structure used in code according to 64 bits for example replace int type with NSInteger, Float with CGFloat, etc.

I also faced similar issue, hence solved this issue by updating data type used for 64 bits as range differs w.r.t to 32 bits.

Find solution in below link, by update the iCarousel third party library.

link:  https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Answer (score 0):

ipad4 is armv7, iphone6 need armv7s so you might need to add armv7s

Comment: Can you add some more details about what you mean?

Comment: i6 is arm64. adding armv7s hardly matters.