# UIButton setImage: forState not working with 64 bit architecture

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, 64-bit, arm64

I have existing project created a year ago. After AppStore's 64 bit requirement announcements, I had to include `arm64` architecture into my project

But after adding `arm64` into `appTarget -> Build Settings -> Valid Architectures` all the `setImage: forState` methods of all `UIButton` objects stopped working, while `setBackGroundImage: forState` is working normally.

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

To test this oddity I created new project and created `UIButton` and used `setImage: forState` method, everything is working as expected.

If I remove back `arm64` architecture, every thing is ok with my project. 
I don't know what I did wrong with my project.

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution? I've been testing for 3 days!

Comment: I don't remember exactly how did I fixed this problem. But if I'm not mistaken, it should be some method created in UIImage (or UIColor) class category casing this bug. So check your class categories, if they are overriding any native methods.

Comment: I think the answer is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20944188/1178825

Comment: yep, I remembered it should be `setAlpha:` method created in UIButton category.

Answer (score 0):

You should use UIControlState tydef instead of int [1]

`[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal]`