# Is there a typical way of informing the user a UITableView is scrollable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Back in the pre-iOS 7 days with grouped tables, it was easy for the user to tell if a `UITableView` had more content on it that needed to be scrolled to.  With the way tables are displayed now, though, it seems hard to know ahead of time if a table is showing all of it's data or if there is more data hidden that the user needs to scroll to in order to see it.

**Is there a typical way of informing the user that there is more content in the table than is being shown?  If not, does anyone have any ideas of how I could do it?**  I've seen it before where there would be a floating arrow overlay that would appear on the side of a table if it can be scrolled in a given direction, but I think it was on a Windows or Android device, and I don't recall ever seeing it on an iOS device.  I also found [this question concerning always showing the scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888647/uiscrollview-showing-the-scroll-bar), but the answers there say it is either impossible or the comments suggest that they are poorly implemented. Has anyone ever come up with a good way to do this?

EDIT: Just for clarification, I'm developing on iPad with multiple small tables imbedded side-by-side in a single `UIViewController`, which is a bit atypical, so a lot of quick tricks won't work.  Some of these tables will need to be scrolled to show all of their content, and some will be sized such that all the content will always be visible.  Since there is so much going on in each screen, I need a permanent way of indicating the tables can be scrolled, because I don't want my user missing it.

Comment: You maybe accounting for very few percentage of users who may not know to scroll up and down when they see a UITableView. I sometimes have to do that in my app if one of the options is deep below in a grouped tableview. I usually tell them using UIAlertView when they first install my app. Simple and easy.

Comment: @SamBudda: My screens have many tables imbedded in them, and some of them are sized so that they will never need to be scrolled.  Others will need to be scrolled.  I want an easy way for my users to know which is which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I'm going to go with SAKrisT's method [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888647/uiscrollview-showing-the-scroll-bar).  It makes a category on `UIImageView`, which is what the scrollbars on a `UIScrollView` are subclasses of.

The Category:

```
//.h
#define noDisableVerticalScrollTag 836913
#define noDisableHorizontalScrollTag 836914

//.m
@implementation UIImageView (ForScrollView)

- (void) setAlpha:(float)alpha {

    if (self.superview.tag == noDisableVerticalScrollTag) {
        if (alpha == 0 && self.autoresizingMask == UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin) {
            if (self.frame.size.width < 10 && self.frame.size.height > self.frame.size.width) {
                UIScrollView *sc = (UIScrollView*)self.superview;
                if (sc.frame.size.height < sc.contentSize.height) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (self.superview.tag == noDisableHorizontalScrollTag) {
        if (alpha == 0 && self.autoresizingMask == UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin) {
            if (self.frame.size.height < 10 && self.frame.size.height < self.frame.size.width) {
                UIScrollView *sc = (UIScrollView*)self.superview;
                if (sc.frame.size.width < sc.contentSize.width) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [super setAlpha:alpha];
}
@end
```

To use this, in the code for the viewController that holds the table:

```
#import "UIImageView+ForScrollView.h"
// ... Stuff ...
- (void) viewDidAppear
{
    [super viewDidAppear];

    myTableView.tag = noDisableVerticalScrollTag;
    [myTableView flashScrollIndicators];
    // ... Stuff ...
}
// ... Stuff ...
```

Note that `myTableView.tag` can be set anywhere, but `[myTableView flashScrollIndicators];` has to be called no sooner than `viewDidAppear` (so NOT in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` - it seems like they cannot be flashed if the table has not been displayed yet).

This method works, but it ties up the `.tag` property of the table, so that tag can't be used for anything else, which might be a problem for some people.

Comment: Above code 
Create problem on iOS 64 bit devices. If I am using this catergory images are not displaying or load on views in iOS 64 bit devices. Use native objective-c or swift method-: 

    [tableView flashScrollIndicators] 

add this code in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.
 Read more about flashScrollIndicators on here- 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW35

Answer (score 4):

A great pattern I've seen is to call [`-flashScrollIndicators`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW35) after the table view appears. This gives the user a visual indication that scrolling would do something, while not requiring any permanent modification to the table view's drawing.

Comment: Yeah that's what most of the suggestions in the question I linked said.  I'm looking for something permanent though.  I'm developing an iPad app, and there is a lot of information shown on my screen in different places, so if I flash it just once, the user might miss it.  I could flash it at some time interval, but that would just get annoying after a while.

Answer (score 0):

I try to use a more natural approach in my apps, and that is to size my cells such that the last visible cell in the table is "cut off." Ideally it's best if it's cut off across text or an image so that the user immediately understands there is more, but sometimes that's difficult to do, especially if you implement dynamic text resizing.

[image: Example]

Of course, modern users are mostly familiar with scrolling so often no indicator is necessary.

Here's another example of a more natural way to let them know there is more content. Notice that not only are the letters cut off on the bottom, but there is also a lot of room at the top; this gives a further visual indicator that the text can be scrolled into the negative space to reveal more.

[image: Example 2]

Comment: Its a good approach but you cannot guarantee it. What about iPhone 4 or iPad screen sizes?

Comment: Yeah, I thought of trying to do this, but some of my cells are going to have non-default height, and for some tables different cells could even have different heights.  So trying to re-size my tables so some of the content bleeds off will get pretty messy pretty fast.  I need a better way.