# Show scrollbar in UITableView before the table is dragged down. In a Way, the UIScrollBar should always be visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

In a I am using several **UITableView** in my app. Some of them contain several rows, while some have two three only. What I need is: if the table contains several rows, then the **scrollbar should be visible before the user even drags the table down**.
Or in another way, is it possible to make scrollbar visible always??

Comment: UITableView's scrollBar only visible when your content it larger then height of your UITableView..

Comment: Yes I know that. In that case only, I want the scroll indicator to show always.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can flash them but there isn't an option to make them always visible:

```
[ScrollView flashScrollIndicators];
```

> UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView,So you can use it directly with it

```
  - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
      [super viewDidAppear:animated];
      [self.tableView performSelector:@selector(flashScrollIndicators) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}
```

Check out for more info :
[UIScrollView - showing the scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888647/uiscrollview-showing-the-scroll-bar)

**Swift:**

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.tableView.flashScrollIndicators()   
}
```

Comment: Ok. but how to access the scrollbar of a UItableView??

Comment: i tried doing [[self.table superclass]  flashScrollIndicators].. but it does not work..

Comment: UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so you should just use the table view directly.

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 3.0**

**1) Timer**

```
var timerForShowScrollIndicator: Timer?
```

**2) Methods**

```
/// Show always scroll indicator in table view
func showScrollIndicatorsInContacts() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.001) {
        self.tableView.flashScrollIndicators()
    }
}

/// Start timer for always show scroll indicator in table view
func startTimerForShowScrollIndicator() {
    self.timerForShowScrollIndicator = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.3, target: self, selector: #selector(self.showScrollIndicatorsInContacts), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

/// Stop timer for always show scroll indicator in table view
func stopTimerForShowScrollIndicator() {
    self.timerForShowScrollIndicator?.invalidate()
    self.timerForShowScrollIndicator = nil
}
```

**3) Use**

**startTimerForShowScrollIndicator** in **viewDidAppear**

**stopTimerForShowScrollIndicator** in **viewDidDisappear**

Answer (score 1):

```
    var timerForIndicatore:Timer?
           
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                super.viewDidAppear(animated)
                
                showIndicator()
            }
            
         
       override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
                super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
                
                deinitializeIndicator()
            }


 @objc func startContinuosShowingIndicator() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0001) {
            self.deviceListTableView.flashScrollIndicators()
        }
    }

    func showIndicator() {
        self.timerForIndicatore = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.3, target: self, selector: #selector(self.startContinuosShowingIndicator), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func deinitializeIndicator() {
        self.timerForIndicatore?.invalidate()
        self.timerForIndicatore = nil
    }
```

Comment: You might consider adding some description/explaination on why and how this solves his problem

Comment: @yudhisther just sharing my understanding to the code. The process is, having a timer that repeatedly call the `UIScrollView.flashScrollIndicators()` every 300ms. Hope this answers your question