# Xamarin Forms ListView for iOS: Always Show ScrollBar

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a `ProductList` of type `ObservableCollection<Product>` where `Product` is a class given below:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

In my Xamarin Forms iOS Application, I have a `ListView` whose `ItemSource` is `ProductList`. When number of Products in the `ProductList` is so that the height of `ListView` is not enough to show all of them, additional items can be reached by scrolling the `ListView`. However, I want the ScrollBar that is displayed only when scrolling the `ListView` to be displayed always. Is it possible or should I try another UI besides `ListViev` to be able to always show ScrollBar.

There are some solutions for Xamarin.Android but I couldn't find any effective solution for the iOS App.

Thank you very much...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888647/uiscrollview-showing-the-scroll-bar maybe help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Cole commented, the `flashScrollIndicators` can only show the indicator a short time.

So, you have to customize a scroll indicator.

**Create a custom renderer of the ListView and add your custom scroll indicator**, like this:

```
    public class MyListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        public UIView bar;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            //Hide the default Scroll Indicator.
            Control.ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;


            //Set Delegate
            CustomScrollDelegate customScrollDelegate = new CustomScrollDelegate();
            Control.Delegate = customScrollDelegate;

            //Create the background view of custom indicator.
            double frameHeight = Control.Frame.Size.Height;
            double frameWidth = Control.Frame.Size.Width;

            double barBackgroundWidth = 6;
            double statusBarHeight = 20;

            UIView barBackgroundView = new UIView();
            CGRect barBVRect = new CGRect(frameWidth - barBackgroundWidth, statusBarHeight, barBackgroundWidth, frameHeight);
            barBackgroundView.Frame = barBVRect;
            barBackgroundView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;
            barBackgroundView.Layer.CornerRadius = 2;
            barBackgroundView.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;


            //Create the bar of the custom indicator.
            bar = new UIView();
            CGRect barRect = new CGRect(1, 0, 4, 0);
            bar.Frame = barRect;
            bar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
            bar.Layer.CornerRadius = 2;
            bar.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;

            //Add the views to the superview of the tableview.
            barBackgroundView.AddSubview(bar);
            Control.Superview.AddSubview(barBackgroundView);

            //Transfer the bar view to delegate.
            customScrollDelegate.bar = bar;

        }

        public override void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews();
            Console.WriteLine("End of loading!!!");
            double contentHeight = Control.ContentSize.Height;
            double frameHeight = Control.Frame.Size.Height;
            double barHeight = frameHeight * frameHeight / contentHeight;


            //Reset the bar height when the table view finishes loading.
            CGRect barRect = new CGRect(bar.Frame.X, bar.Frame.Y, bar.Frame.Width, barHeight);
            bar.Frame = barRect;
        }

    }
```

**Implement the `Scrolled` delegate which tracks the scrolling action of the scrollView.** You can update the position of the indicator in the delegate.

```
    public class CustomScrollDelegate : UIKit.UITableViewDelegate
    {
        public UIView bar;
        double barY;

        public override void Scrolled(UIScrollView scrollView)
        {
            double y = scrollView.ContentOffset.Y;
            double contentHeight = scrollView.ContentSize.Height;
            double frameHeight = scrollView.Frame.Size.Height;

            double barHeight = frameHeight * frameHeight / contentHeight;
            barY = y / (contentHeight - frameHeight) * (frameHeight - barHeight);

            //Cut the bar Height when it over the top.
            if (barY < 0)
            {
                barHeight = barHeight + barY;
                barY = 0;
            }

            //Cut the bar height when it over the bottom.
            if (barY > (frameHeight - barHeight))
            {
               barHeight = barHeight - (barY - (frameHeight - barHeight));
            }

            //Reset the barView rect. Let's move!!!
            CGRect barRect = new CGRect(bar.Frame.X, barY, bar.Frame.Width, barHeight);
            bar.Frame = barRect;

        }

    }
```

**It works like this:**

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I asked for. However there are some points that I couldn't understand.

Comment: 1 ) Isn't the `barY` top point of the scrollbar? This is because when scrollbar is at the top, value of `y` is  `(contentHeight - frameHeight)/2`, so value of `barY` is `(frameHeight - barHeight)/2`. Shouldn't it be 0 when scrollbar is at the top?

Comment: 2) //Cut the bar height when it over the bottom. Why did you choose `(barY > (contentHeight - frameHeight))`? I think when it is over the bottom `barY > frameHeight - barHeight`

Comment: @Jose, 1). Yes, `barY` is the top of the scrollbar. It should be 0 at the top. How do you get the `y` is `(contentHeight - frameHeight)/2` ? `y` should be 0 and `barY` is 0 too.

Comment: @Jose, 2). Sorry, it is my mistake. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Another thing: `barHeight` decreases when it hits the top and bottom even if I comment out the two conditions about the `barY`. Do I misinterpret the function of those two `if`s

Comment: @Jose, No, you got the point. The `if`s are used to decrease the `barHeight` when it hit the top and bottom as the native indicator action.

Comment: 1) `y` is defined as the offset for the origin of the content inside of a scrollview, relative to the origin of the scrollview itself. When scrollbar is at the top; origin of the scrollview is at `frameHeight/2` and  origin of the content is at `contentHeight/2`, both referenced to the top of scrollview. Therefore, distance between them becomes `(contentHeight - frameHeight)/2`

Comment: Then why `barHeight` decreases when I delete those two conditions?

Comment: No, they didn't decrease. They just move out of the screen. As my gif, if I remove the `if` for top, it will move onto the status bar.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest @Kevin. This helped me a lot to improve my understanding of custom renderers and UIViews

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me, I'm using UIKit.UIScrollViewDelegate