# How to make the scroll bar visible always in xamarin forms in ios device and shift the scroll bar to left side of the screen?

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to make the scroll bar always visible in Xamarin forms in IOS device and shift the scroll bar to left side of the screen?
I tried this link:
[Xamarin Forms ListView for iOS: Always Show ScrollBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813371/xamarin-forms-listview-for-ios-always-show-scrollbar)

but getting exception that

> Event registration is overwriting existing delegate. Either just use
>   events or your own delegate: hupp.iOS.Models.CustomScrollDelegate
>   UIKit.UIScrollView+_UIScrollViewDelegate

```
    public class CustomScrollViewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
{

    public UIView bar;

    protected override async void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
       // UIScrollView iosScrollView = (UIScrollView)NativeView;

        this.ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = ((CustomScrollViewLesson)e.NewElement).IsVerticalScrollbarEnabled;
        this.ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = ((CustomScrollViewLesson)e.NewElement).IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabled;

        this.IndicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle.White;
        this.ScrollIndicatorInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 30, 0, 30);
        this.FlashScrollIndicators();
        //Hide the default Scroll Indicator.
         this.ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
        //Set Delegate
        CustomScrollDelegate customScrollDelegate = new CustomScrollDelegate();
        this.Delegate = customScrollDelegate;


        //Create the background view of custom indicator.
        double frameHeight = this.Frame.Size.Height;
        double frameWidth = this.Frame.Size.Width;

        double barBackgroundWidth = 6;
        double statusBarHeight = 20; //this.ScrollIndicatorInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 0, this.Bounds.Size.Width - 10);
        UIView barBackgroundView = new UIView();
        CGRect barBVRect = new CGRect(frameWidth - barBackgroundWidth, statusBarHeight, barBackgroundWidth, frameHeight);
        barBackgroundView.Frame = barBVRect;
        barBackgroundView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;
        barBackgroundView.Layer.CornerRadius = 2;
        barBackgroundView.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;

        //Create the bar of the custom indicator.
        bar = new UIScrollView();
        CGRect barRect = new CGRect(1, 0, 4, 0);
        bar.Frame = barRect;
        bar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        bar.Layer.CornerRadius = 2;
        bar.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;

        //Add the views to the superview of the tableview.
        barBackgroundView.AddSubview(bar);
        this.Superview.AddSubview(barBackgroundView);//here also getting exception null value in superview.so i commented while debug
        customScrollDelegate.bar = bar;

        //Transfer the bar view to delegate.

    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();
        Console.WriteLine("End of loading!!!");
        double contentHeight = this.ContentSize.Height;
        double frameHeight = this.Frame.Size.Height;
        double barHeight = frameHeight * frameHeight / contentHeight;


        //Reset the bar height when the table view finishes loading.
        CGRect barRect = new CGRect(bar.Frame.X, bar.Frame.Y, bar.Frame.Width, barHeight);
        bar.Frame = barRect;
    }
}
    public class CustomScrollDelegate : UIKit.UIScrollViewDelegate
{
    public UIView bar;
    double barY;

    public override void Scrolled(UIScrollView scrollView)
    {
        double y = scrollView.ContentOffset.Y;
        double contentHeight = scrollView.ContentSize.Height;
        double frameHeight = scrollView.Frame.Size.Height;

        double barHeight = frameHeight * frameHeight / contentHeight;
        barY = y / (contentHeight - frameHeight) * (frameHeight - barHeight);

        //Cut the bar Height when it over the top.
        if (barY < 0)
        {
            barHeight = barHeight + barY;
            barY = 0;
        }

        //Cut the bar height when it over the bottom.
        if (barY > (frameHeight - barHeight))
        {
            barHeight = barHeight - (barY - (frameHeight - barHeight));
        }

        //Reset the barView rect. Let's move!!!
        CGRect barRect = new CGRect(bar.Frame.X, barY, bar.Frame.Width, barHeight);
        bar.Frame = barRect;

    }

}
```

Please give a solution and thanks in advance

Comment: Hi , could you share the xaml code used of project , then we can know which layout designed (ScrollView or ListView uesd) .

Comment: only scrollview using,listview is not using,so i changed to CustomScrollDelegate : UIKit.UIScrollViewDelegate instead CustomScrollDelegate : UIKit.UITableViewDelegate

Comment: OK , thanks for replying,  I will check it in ScrollView  .If sharing with code about CustomScrollDelegate , that will be better .

Comment: Thanks a lot ,i updated the code above..

Comment: Thanks for sharing , I will check it . If solution will update here .