# Xamarin Forms VerticalScrollBarVisibility does not work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, scrollview, scrollbar

I am using the multi-platform Xamarin Forms and on all scrollable elements like `scrollview`, `listview`, `collectionview` none of them permanently show the scrollbar with the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` parameter by using the *Always* flag. It only shows when you are swiping on the element, but I want it to always be showing on both IOS and Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by Xamarin.forms so far and there is an open [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8209) in Github.

In Android, you can use custom renderer to achieve that:

```
class MyScrollviewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
{
    public MyScrollviewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        this.ScrollbarFadingEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

In iOS, the native iOS does not support this too and you have to write your own scroll bar:

Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813371/xamarin-forms-listview-for-ios-always-show-scrollbar) may help.

Relevant thread: [Make scrollbar always visible on UIScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697215/make-scrollbar-always-visible-on-uiscrollview)

Comment: While I wish the feature that is listed in the Xamarin official documentation would actually work, this looks like a viable option as a workaround. Also the bug you linked is not the correct one, I think [this one](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8015) might be it

Comment: I just faced this issue also, kinda weird that they put it in the doc but it doesn't work.