# Xamarin Horizontal Collection View with peakareinset

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using a collection view to show items in an horizontal list, however it has been noted that if the last item in the list is not visible that it might not be clear that there is another item.

unlike carousel the collection view does not have a peakareainset where you can just see a bit of the item so that the user knows that they need to scroll .

How can I achieve the look where you always see a bit of last item in an horizontal collectionview?

What I have

[image]

What I would like to have

[image: a]

Also if I put
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always" does not work as expected as I don't see the horizontal scrolling till you start moving the items. mmm

```
   <CollectionView  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                    ItemsLayout="HorizontalList" 
                    ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureFirstItem" 
                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                           Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           HeightRequest="60" 
                           WidthRequest="60" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, you can create a custom renderer of `CollectionView` to make the `HorizontalScrollBar` always visiable:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.CollectionView), typeof(MyCollectionViewRenderer))]    
namespace App332.Droid
{
    class MyCollectionViewRenderer : CollectionViewRenderer
    {
        public MyCollectionViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ItemsView> elementChangedEvent)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(elementChangedEvent);

            this.ScrollbarFadingEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that . can you do the same for iOS?

Comment: The native iOS does not support this feature too. So you have to implement it by yourself. Have a look at these thread may help: [Xamarin Forms ListView for iOS: Always Show ScrollBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813371/xamarin-forms-listview-for-ios-always-show-scrollbar) and [Make scrollbar always visible on UIScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697215/make-scrollbar-always-visible-on-uiscrollview).

Comment: If my answer helps you, please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).